# Python import only works when run from inside package directory

Tags: python, import, module, python-import

I have a python script which uses [gentle](https://github.com/lowerquality/gentle) to transcribe some audio.

At the moment I have to copy my file into the gentle repo and then I can `import gentle` and use `gentle` later in the code as I would like.

However I would prefer not to have to copy my file into the gentle directory. I have tried changing the import to `import gentle.gentle` but either way I get the following error when running my script from the parent directory:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_text.py", line 6, in <module>
    import gentle.gentle  # or just import gentle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gentle/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from resources import Resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gentle/resources.py", line 4, in <module>
    from util.paths import get_resource, ENV_VAR
ImportError: No module named util.paths
```

Is there an easy way to use the module without having to copy my script into its directory? Thank you!

Comment: This question is tricky to answer in a straightforward way, because there's several ways to approach this. But my recommendation would be to properly **package** your script/project, and then declare `gentle` as a **dependency** of it, allowing you to install your own package like you would with other Python packages. Have a look at https://packaging.python.org - particularly the [Packaging and Distributing Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/) section for details on how to create your own Python package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many fixes to this issue, see the tutorial page on the docs for more info https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html.

Basically, if `gentle` is pip-installable you may want to try to install it using:

```
pip install --user gentle
```

Or you may want to create an environment with either `conda` or `virtualenv`.
Alternatively, you could just set your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include the path you need, e.g.

```
PYTHONPATH="/path/to/lib:$PYTHONPATH" python /path/to/script.py
```